# Adobe Flex Development on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-flex, netbeans, ubuntu, maven, flexmojos

I'm thinking the following:

- Netbeans + FlexBeans
- Maven + FlexMojos

---

However:

- FlexBeans just doesn't compare with FlexBuilder
- Not sure FlexMojos supports Flex 4

---

How do you guys manage to develop Flex apps on Ubuntu?

I personally prefer Netbeans to Eclipse. Netbeans has very good Maven project support. So I am thinking of:

- "Extending" FlexMojos to work with Flex 4
- Forking or developing from scratch a good Flex plugin for Netbeans\

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh wait, does the SDK support non Windows OS's? I'm seeing only .exe's in the Flex 4 SDKs. :-(

Comment: ....... Found this: http://stevelove.org/2009/05/14/how-to-install-and-set-up-adobe-flex-sdk-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been developing with Flex on Ubuntu for the last 6 months with IntelliJ IDEA 9.

Besides many interesting features (that Flex Builder 3 does not have), the editor supports Maven and FlexMojos nicely. You can actually just import your poms directly into IDEA and it will create all configurations for you. This is also interesting if you are using a build server that uses Maven so you don't have to maintain multiple build configurations.

- IntelliJ IDEA: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/
- FlexMojos: http://code.google.com/p/flex-mojos/

Comment: More than a year after I asked this question, I'm on Ubuntu with IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 Ultimate. It's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Give a go to FDT, they've just added MXML support. It's not cheap by any means, but worth trying.

Cheers, J

Answer (score 1):

> However:
>
> ```
> * Not sure FlexMojos supports Flex 4
> ```

http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/

Answer (score 0):

Adobe is working on a [Linux version of Flex Builder](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/).

SapphireSteel has a plugin for Visual Studio called [Amethyst](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Adobe-Flex-In-Visual-Studio)

Ensemble has another one called [Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml)

Comment: I don't like Eclipse, I don't like FlexBuilder.. :-)

Comment: What don't you like about them? (Personally I don't like them because I'm used to Visual Studio and IMO nothing compares to it. But until Visual Studio supports Flex development.......)

Comment: Hmm.. I accidentally used Netbeans 6x once, and found Eclipse in comparison to be amateurish.

Comment: @Pedro, Just my personal opinion. For me, Eclipse looks like a bunch of modules bundled together rather than a unified IDE. Of course, I am not trying to convert anyone. If you feel you are productive with Eclipse, please go ahead and continue using it.

Comment: Adobe's progress on this has been glacial.  At times it was even suspended.  If you want to see it happen, please cast your vote here:  https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-19053

Answer (score 0):

I develop Flex apps that run on Linux. I run VMWare on Centos and run Vista on that and have FlexBuilder installed in the virtual machine. It works pretty well since I found the Linux FlexBuilder to be very buggy and I can still use Linux for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unsanctioned project to get Flash Builder 4 to run on Linux.  I have tried it out and it works very well.  The only real missing feature is design mode.

http://code.google.com/p/fb4linux/